# Cannot show image from STATIC_FOLDER in Flask template

Tags: python, flask

I set folder for static files like this

```
app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'] = 'tmp'
```

In template i use img tag to show an image stored in /tmp:

```
<img src='IKE2low.jpg' width="200" height="85">
```

In firebug i see 404 error instead of image. Please tell me what did i do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little update: now i tried to put this file next to my main py file and also in template folder - still there is no picture seen by img tag. I wonder - where does it search for images???

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm not sure what is this `STATIC_FOLDER` configuration item you are using. Where did you find it?

There are actually two arguments to the `Flask` class constructor that govern the configuration of static files:

- **static_folder**: defaults to "static". This is the prefix that you have to use in URLs to access the static files.
- **static_url_path**: this is the disk location of the static folder. By default this value is the same as the static_folder setting.

For example, if you use this configuration:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path = "/tmp", static_folder = "tmp")
```

Then you can access your images as follows:

```
<img src='/tmp/IKE2low.jpg' width="200" height="85">
```

You can also remove the need to have a prefix in the URLs as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path = "", static_folder = "tmp")
```

And then you can access your images as:

```
<img src='/IKE2low.jpg' width="200" height="85">
```

Note that you still need to have a root `/`.

But the best way to do this is to not reference image paths explicitly and instead use `url_for` to generate the correct URLs. If you are using Jinja2 templates that would be:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'IKE2low.jpg') }}" width="200" height="85">
```

This last expression would work regardless of where and how the static files are configured.

Comment: Miguel, did you perhaps criss-cross your definitions for static_folder, static_url_path? I notice that later you use static_url_path to refer to that text prepending a resource url.