# Why images can be shown only if they are in `static` folder?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm building a image recognition Flask project. And I want the image shown on the web page. Here is the structure of my project:

[image]

As you can see, `static`,`templates` and `upload` are in the same folder. If I save the image into `static` folder (which is generated by the VS2015 flask project) and write the `result.html` like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<h3>{{ outcome_info }}</h3>
<html lang="zh-cmn-Hans">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flood Classifier</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=thename)}}">
</body>
</html>
```

The image would shown successfully when this Python function is called:

```
@app.route('/classify', methods=['POST','GET'])
def classify():
    global image
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)
    result = model.predict(image)
    if result[0][0] == 1:
        result = "flood"
    else:
        result = "no flood"
    return render_template('result.html', thename = imagename, outcome_info = result)
```

However, if I save the image file into `upload` (which is created by myself), and just change the folder name in `result.html` like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<h3>{{ outcome_info }}</h3>
<html lang="zh-cmn-Hans">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flood Classifier</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <img src="{{url_for('upload', filename=thename)}}">
</body>
</html>
```

The image would not shown when call that Python function. Do the images **must** be saved into `static` folder or there is something that I misunderstand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this configuration:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path = "/upload", static_folder = "upload")
```

Then you can access your images as follows:

```
<img src='/upload/image1.jpg' width="200" height="85">
```

check this answer for more details: [Cannot show image from STATIC_FOLDER in Flask template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764156/cannot-show-image-from-static-folder-in-flask-template)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how `url_for` works.

The first parameter is `endpoint`, `endpoint` is roughly a registered route handler. And `static` is a built-in route handler which handles all requests to `http://yourserver/static/xxxx`.

When you set `static_folder`, you set the flask to serve all files under that folder through route `static`. You can also override this default route by setting `static_url_path`.

[doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files)